# Django foreign key starting with nothing

Tags: python, django, django-models, null

So often it is important to have a `ForeignKey` connection that starts with nothing and then has something `add`ed

here are my `model`s

```
class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    threshold = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator
        (100),MinValueValidator(60)])
    works = models.ForeignKey(Work,null=True) #blank=True also doesn't work
```

so I create a class that has no `Work`, which logically makes sense:

```
math = Class("math",90)
math.save()
```

now lets say we have `homework` and `quizzes` that are `Work` instances:

```
math.works.add(homework,quizzes)
#gives the following error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

`math.works` is clearly empty to start, and that makes sense, but this will not let me add anything!

**How would I be able to start a ForeignKey with nothing and then be able to `add` to it?**

Comment: Either you have your relationship backwards or you need a many-to-many relationship instead. Can a given `Work` instance belong to more than one `Class` at a time?

Comment: No, 'Work' is individual to each `Class`. The reason for this is that homework might be 10% in one class and 20% in another, so a `Work` instance can only belong to one `Class`. I had many-to-many relationships previously, and everything worked, but then I realized that foreignkey made more sense. So I redid everything accordingly, and I can't get passed this error

Comment: your foreign key has to be in work model, not in class, as work knows its class, but class has many works

Comment: @alko will `Class` still be able to access all of the works easily and target specific ones?

Comment: @RyanSaxe yep, it can with standard django orm, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents.
First, i think you should move your foreignkey to work class not in Class class. add() is for manytomany field[See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects)

```
class work(models.Model):
.....
subject = models.ForeignKey(Class,null=True)
```

So that the relationship is built as your intention. homework, quizzes as instances of work class both are related to math as an instance of Class class.

when you try to save, do as following:

```
>>> homework = work.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> math = Class.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> homework.subject = math
>>> homework.save()
>>> quizzes = work.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> math = Class.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> quizzes.subject = math
>>> quizzes.save()
```

Now you can retrieve all the work for given Class:

```
math = Class.objects.get(pk=1)
math.work_set.all()
```

it will return you all the instances that are related to math, and in your case, will be homework and quizzes.

Comment: you'd better not `class = ...`